# Creating Scheduled Task in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scheduled-tasks

I am creating an application in `javascript` which send notification on every **sunday 12.00 am.**
What should I do to call a function on that time.

Comment: show us more info's, what u have done so far ?

Comment: for starters, you have [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [setInteval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to check Date

Comment: Will the JavaScript be persistent (i.e. server-side service / cron job) or transient (i.e. client-side web page)?

Comment: Ah, I see you've edited your comment. Well, that makes mine useless, deleting. :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. Anyway I answred how it can be done (but shouldn't...)

Comment: @gdoron: Looks about right. +1

Answer (score 12):

### I wouldn't do it with javascript

That said(with shouting...)

```
function foo(){
    var day =new Date().getDay();
    var hours =new Date().getHours();
    
    if (day === 0 && hours >12 && hours < 13)  // day is a 0 index base
                                               // sunday between 12:00 and 13:00
        // Do what you want here:
}

setInterval(foo, 3600000); // one hour check.
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bGSuD/1)
​

Comment: so what would you do it with?

Comment: @ChristopherStrydom, with server side code. C#\Java\Ruby\PHP etc'.

Comment: @George, I don't believe this is the case here as the OP didn't mention nodejs in his question text\tags\comments.

Answer (score -2):

another solution is 3rd parties like: [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0 0 0 * * 0', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every sunday, 12 am');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```