# How to delete data from a Firebase database on a schedule

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, visual-studio-cordova

I have created a simple chatroom-like Apache Cordova (HTML) application that allows users to add their own messages with custom usernames in the chatroom.

The messages add up after a while and i have to go into the actual database to delete them every day to avoid clutter.

Is there any way i can create a rule or a javascript function to clear the data at a certain time every day?  For instance at 9 am the database would clear all its content from the previous day and night and start the day fresh.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if ur using mongodb, this would help http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it there are two current similar solutions: [Creating Scheduled Task in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516491/creating-scheduled-task-in-javascript) ||
[Later.js execute Function on Schedule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011783/later-js-execute-function-on-schedule)

I am unfamiliar with later.js so I can't help you there.

Using gdoron's code, I believe the code should look similar to this:

```
function foo(){
    var day =new Date().getDay();
    var hours =new Date().getHours();

    if (day === 0 && hours >12 && hours < 13)  // day is a 0 index base
                                               // sunday between 12:00 and 13:00

//What you want to do goes here
var fredRef = new Firebase('yourDirectoryUrl')
fredRef.remove();

}

setInterval(foo, 3600000); // one hour check.
```

Notes:

Remember to include

```
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
```

Also, keep in mind this will clear EVERYTHING.

Comment: I feel database-clearing should be done from server side, not by invoking from client side. As above solution wont work, if user is offline?

Comment: Yea it is definitely better done server side. But the question asked for a javascript function as a solution. gdoron mentions in the first link "C#\Java\Ruby\PHP" would probably be better.

Comment: Thanks for the help!   the setInterval call will run the foo function every hour?

Comment: @JonathanLin do you know of a way to complete this action on the server side? Is there a rule i can add to my firebase database so that preforms the same function as the method above?

Comment: @DustinHux I'm actually unaware of what kind of schedule they are passing to the setInterval function, but as far as I know, the second argument is the interval in milliseconds. (3,600,000 ms is 1 hour). Also after some small researching, the only way I see to mess with firebase on a server side is to use the REST api. Unfortunately I'm only familiar with firebase' javascript.